# concept and conception

Tags: vocabulary

> Constitutional law is political because it results from choices rooted in fundamental social `concepts` like liberty and property.

This is from one multiple choice, and I made it wrongly by choosing `conceptions`.

What's the difference in the common meaning of `concept` and `conception`?

If this is not one multiple choice, can I use `conceptions`?

One common meaning:

> {{concept,Noun}->an abstract or general idea inferred or derived from specific instances}
>   {conception,Noun,Idea}->an abstract or general idea inferred or derived from specific instances

[image]

Comment: Hello, HyperGroups!  Have you looked up both *concept* and *conception* in the dictionary?  What did you find?

Comment: @snailboat They have common meaning: notion/idea in some dictionaries.

Comment: Hmm, would you mind linking to that dictionary definition? I find it odd that they'd give them the same definition word for word. I'm interested to see what else they say about the words.

Comment: @WendiKidd Ok,I've added one image of definition. This is got from WolframAlpha's WordData[], and I've looked up some English-Chinese dictionaries, they both have the common meaning `notion`/`idea`

Comment: It's using [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=concept) data.  I would suggest you use a different source of information.  (I'm hesitant to call WordNet a dictionary!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use *conception* when talking about an idea or notion that someone *has*. When used in this sense, it always belongs to someone, or to a group of people. A *concept* is simply an idea or notion, in an abstract sense. It belongs to no one.

For example, you and I may agree that:

> Freedom is a *concept*.

...in that we both agree that there exists an idea called "freedom." However, it is possible that:

> Your *conception* of freedom differs from mine.

...in that if we were both asked to define freedom, we would give two different answers. Your mental model of the *concept* of freedom is *your conception* of it.